# How to remove (not replace) a fragment present in FrameLayout?

Tags: android-fragments

I have the ID of a FrameLayout which hosts different fragments (identified by different tags) at any given time. I sometimes wish to remove (not replace) whatever fragment is currently in the FrameLayout container. Here is what I tried and did not work:

```
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout_container);
if (f != null) {
    txn.remove(f);
}
txn.commit();
```

So, I'm passing the ID of the container and if anything comes back (I was expecting a fragment currently in the container) I want to remove it.

Problem is that when I call above again (another UI event like button click), the findFragmentById returns the exact same Fragment again, as if prior remove/commit didn't do anything.

Btw, replace() works fine -- I'm struggling with the remove() only.

Answer (score 1):

After spending more time on above problem, I discovered that calling remove() doesn't actually remove the fragment from the FragmentManager (duh) -- i.e. subsequent calls to findFragmentById still return the original fragment. What remove() does to the fragment is it changes its "isAdded" state, specifically:

- fragment.isAdded() returns false
- fragment.isDetached() returns false
- fragment.isInLayout() returns false
- fragment.isHidden() returns false

(jeez, haven't they exhausted all verbs by now?)

I expected the fragment to be actually removed from the manager after calling remove(), sort of like removing a node from a DOM tree. Silly me.